# Mysql: Combine 2 queries in one (both have their own group by...)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make only one query out of the following, but can't find a way to do it (The thing is the hard coded date is depending on a grand parent column right now so as mysql won't admit that I'm trying to do that in 1 query instead of creating a temporary table just for the sake of it.

```
select sum(result) 
from 
(
    SELECT 
      round(SUM(sr3.F_RESULT)/count(distinct(sr3.f_subgame_id))) as result,
      sr3.f_team_id
    FROM t_subgames_results sr3
    JOIN t_subgames s3 on s3.f_subgame_id = sr3.f_subgame_id
    JOIN t_seasons_games sg3 on sg3.f_game_id = s3.f_game_id
    WHERE sg3.f_date < '2012-09-14'
      and sr3.f_result>-1
    GROUP BY sr3.f_player_id
) averageByPlayer
group by f_team_id;
```

As you see, I need to get average results by game by team, but the average has to be calculated on each player (and round up) before the sum by team.

Is there a way to make it only one query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want to do without either a subquery or two completely distinct tables. Each `SELECT` can only aggregate over one set of groups, not two nested level of groups.

However, there *may* be a way to avoid the use of a temporary table. `EXPLAIN` might show you the execution plan, how that query actually gets executed. If there is no mention of a temporary table there, then the MySQL engine already optimized that away. Otherwise, perhaps a slight modification of the query might help. E.g. you could try to include `f_team_id` in the inner `GROUP BY`, preferrably before `f_player_id`.

If that doesn't work, you might want to provide some sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) so users can experiment with that in an attempt to find a formulation which does not use a temporary table. Make sure to include realistic amounts data, as optimization might take the number of table rows into account.

Comment: Thanks MvG, good to know. In the end I realized we missed a requirement which changed completely the query anyway. I realized I had too much logic in it so I'll have a more simple query instead and do the logic somewhere else.